# IllegalThreadStateException? Not Familiar With Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, exception

I have a working java program, a simple mp3 player.

Everything works, can skip tracks, etc... but after a couple of skips (especially back button (previous track), I always get a `IllegalThreadStateException`. I'm not familiar with threads so I'm not sure what to do.

This is for a school assignment, and the MP3 class has been given to us. (cannot be modified)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

MP3 Class (cannot be modified):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;


public class MP3 extends Thread {
  private final File mp3_file;
  private Player player; 

  public MP3(String mp3_path) {
    mp3_file = new File(mp3_path);
}

  public MP3(File mp3) {
    mp3_file = mp3;
}

    public void play() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis     = new FileInputStream(mp3_file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        player = new Player(bis);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem playing file " + mp3_file);
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    // run in new thread to play in background
    start();  // Instructs JVM to call run() in separate thread

  }

  public boolean isPlaying() {
    if (player == null)
        return false;
    else {
        return !player.isComplete();
    }

  }

  public void run() {
    try { player.play(); }
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
  }


      public void quit() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.close(); 
        player = null;
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    return mp3_file.toString();
  }
}
```

My Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MP3Random extends JFrame {

private JPanel backgroundPanel;
private PlaylistPanel playlistPanel;
private MainPanel mainPanel; 

int trackTime;
private MP3 current;

private ButtonListener buttonListener;
private TimerListener timerListener;

private Timer timer;
private boolean playButtonStatus;

public MP3Random() {

    buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
    timerListener = new TimerListener();

    backgroundPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel = new MainPanel();
    playlistPanel = new PlaylistPanel();

    timer = new Timer(1000, timerListener);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    playButtonStatus = false;

    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(650, 400));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    backgroundPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    backgroundPanel.setBorder(null);
    backgroundPanel.add(playlistPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    backgroundPanel.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    getContentPane().add(backgroundPanel);
    setVisible(true);
}

private void playSong(MP3 current) {
    ImageIcon stopIcon = new ImageIcon(MP3Random.class.getResource("/pa2/icons/stop.png"));

      playlistPanel.playList.setSelectedIndex(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current));
    mainPanel.playButton.setIcon(stopIcon);
    trackTime = 0;
    current.play();
    timer.restart();
    mainPanel.trackTitleLabel.setText(getTrackTitle(current.toString()));
}

private void stopPlayback() {
    try {
        current.quit();
        timer.stop();
        playButtonStatus = false;
        mainPanel.trackTitleLabel.setText("");
        mainPanel.trackTimeLabel.setText("");
        mainPanel.playButton.setIcon(mainPanel.playIcon);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {};
}

private String getTrackTitle (String filename) {
    return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filename.lastIndexOf(".mp3"));
}

private String formatTime(int durationInSeconds) {

    int minutes = durationInSeconds / 60;
    int seconds = durationInSeconds % 60;

    return ( (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes
            + ":" + (seconds< 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds );
}

//Panel containing track display/time, media control buttons
private class MainPanel extends JPanel {...}

//Panel containing JList and add/remove from playlist buttons
private class PlaylistPanel extends JPanel {...}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    File[] filesSelected;
    MP3[] mp3List;
    Random generator = new Random();

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource() == playlistPanel.addButton) {
            playlistPanel.fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            playlistPanel.fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

            //FileFilter only allows *.mp3
            playlistPanel.fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            playlistPanel.fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

                public boolean accept(File f) {
                    if (f.isDirectory())
                        return true;

                    String extension = f.toString().substring(f.toString().lastIndexOf('.')+1);
                    if (extension != null) {
                        if (extension.equals("mp3"))
                            return true;
                        else
                            return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                public String getDescription() {
                    return "*.mp3";
                }
            });

            if (playlistPanel.fileChooser.showOpenDialog(MP3Random.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                filesSelected = playlistPanel.fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
                mp3List = new MP3[filesSelected.length];

                mainPanel.playButton.setEnabled(true);
                playlistPanel.removeButton.setEnabled(true);

                //more than 1 file selected
                if (mp3List.length > 1) {
                    mainPanel.shuffleButton.setEnabled(true);
                    mainPanel.nextButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < mp3List.length; i++)
                    playlistPanel.listModel.addElement(mp3List[i] = new MP3(filesSelected[i]));
                current = (MP3) playlistPanel.listModel.get(0);
                playlistPanel.playList.setSelectedIndex(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current));
            }
        }

        //remove button
        if (event.getSource() == playlistPanel.removeButton) {
            Object[] temp = playlistPanel.playList.getSelectedValues();
            for (Object f : temp) {
                playlistPanel.listModel.removeElement(f);
            }

           //1 song in list
           if (playlistPanel.listModel.getSize() == 1) {
               mainPanel.backButton.setEnabled(false);
               mainPanel.nextButton.setEnabled(false);
               mainPanel. shuffleButton.setEnabled(false);
           }

           //no songs in list
           if (playlistPanel.listModel.getSize() == 0) {
               playlistPanel.removeButton.setEnabled(false);
               mainPanel.playButton.setEnabled(false);             
               mainPanel.backButton.setEnabled(false);
               mainPanel.nextButton.setEnabled(false);
               mainPanel.shuffleButton.setEnabled(false);
               current = null;
            }
        }

        //play button
        if (event.getSource() == mainPanel.playButton) {

            //if song not playing
            if (!playButtonStatus) {
                if (!playlistPanel.playList.isSelectedIndex(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current)))
                    current = (MP3) playlistPanel.playList.getSelectedValue();
                playSong(current);                  
                playButtonStatus = true;
            }

            //if song is playing
            else
                stopPlayback();
        }

        //next button
        if (event.getSource() == mainPanel.nextButton) {
            if (!mainPanel.backButton.isEnabled())
                mainPanel.backButton.setEnabled(true);

            if (current.isPlaying()) {
                current.quit();
                current = (MP3) playlistPanel.listModel.get(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current)+1);
                playSong(current);
            }
            else {
                current = (MP3) playlistPanel.listModel.get(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current)+1);
                playlistPanel.playList.setSelectedIndex(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current));
            }

            if (playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current) == playlistPanel.listModel.size() - 1)
                mainPanel.nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        //back button
        if (event.getSource() == mainPanel.backButton) {

            if (!mainPanel.nextButton.isEnabled())
                mainPanel.nextButton.setEnabled(true);  

            if (current.isPlaying()) {
                current.quit();
                current = (MP3) playlistPanel.listModel.get(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current)-1);
                playSong(current);
            }
            else {
                current = (MP3) playlistPanel.listModel.get(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current)-1);
                playlistPanel.playList.setSelectedIndex(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current));
            }

            if (playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current) == 0)
                mainPanel.backButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        //shuffle jlist
        if (event.getSource() == mainPanel.shuffleButton) {
            if (playlistPanel.listModel.size() > 1) {
                int n = playlistPanel.listModel.getSize();
                while (n > 1) {
                    int k = generator.nextInt(n);
                    n--;                 
                    MP3 tempMP3 = (MP3) playlistPanel.listModel.elementAt(n);
                    playlistPanel.listModel.set(n,playlistPanel.listModel.elementAt(k));
                    playlistPanel.listModel.set(k, tempMP3);
                    current = (MP3) playlistPanel.listModel.get(0);
                    playlistPanel.playList.setSelectedIndex(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if (playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current) > 0)
            mainPanel.backButton.setEnabled(true);
        if (playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current) == playlistPanel.listModel.size()-1)
            mainPanel.nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        if (!current.isPlaying()) {
            if (playlistPanel.listModel.size() > 1 && playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current) < playlistPanel.listModel.size()-1) {
                current = (MP3) playlistPanel.listModel.get(playlistPanel.listModel.indexOf(current)+1);
                playSong(current);
            }
            else
                stopPlayback();
        }
        else {
            mainPanel.trackTimeLabel.setText(formatTime(trackTime));
            trackTime++;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    MP3Random instance = new MP3Random();
}
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:656)
at pa2.MP3.play(MP3.java:41)
at pa2.MP3Random.playSong(MP3Random.java:68)
at pa2.MP3Random.access$4(MP3Random.java:62)
at pa2.MP3Random$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(MP3Random.java:373)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6373)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6138)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4735)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
at java.awt.window.dispatchEventImpl(window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is here:

```
public void play() {
  try {
    FileInputStream fis     = new FileInputStream(mp3_file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    player = new Player(bis);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Problem playing file " + mp3_file);
    System.out.println(e);
  }
  // run in new thread to play in background
  start();  // <======== PROBLEM
}
```

The `Thread.Start` [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) says:

> Throws: IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already
>   started.

Basically, a thread cannot started more than once. You will get this exception whenever you call `Play` on an `MP3` instance that has already been started by `MP3.Play()`
What I suggest is to create a new thread to play your track whenever the `MP3.Play` is called.
The player class could look like:

```
public class MP3Player extends Thread {
   public void PlayFile(String soundFile){
      //... Add player logic here
   }
   public void StopPlaying(){
      //.. Stop playing and gracefully exit this thread
   }
}
```

And in the MP3 class:

```
public class MP3{
    MP3Player currentPlayer = null;
    // ...
    public void play() {
       if(currentPlayer != null) currentPlayer.StopPlaying();
       currentPlayer = new MP3Player();
       currentPlayer.PlayFile(mp3_file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the case, since he's passing the MP3-instance to the MP3Random.playSong() method. If your theory holds, he'd have to pass the same MP3-instance each time...Note, that MP3 is-a Thread already!

Comment: the error does occur whenever I press the back/next/play button to play a song that has previously played.

Since I cannot edit the mp3 class, how can I modify my own code around this?

Comment: @Wangagat Then GETah is right. You need to create a new instance of the `MP3`-Class everytime you play a song. You are calling `MP3.play()` multiple times on the same instance - so you are trying to start a thread that has already been started. This does not work.

Comment: ah... I see what you mean.

How would that work, since I'm creating a playlist which populates a DefaultListModel attached to a JList.

The array of selected songs has already created an instance of MP3 class for each selected file in order to populate the array.

Comment: @Wangagat Just updated my post with some code snippet. Please see the update to get an idea on how you can change your code.

Comment: @Wangagat Since you are not allowed to change the MP3-Class, you are stuck with this fact: For every song being played, you need to instantiate an MP3-Instance. Why are you populating the playlist with MP3-Instances? Populate it with `File`s and create the MP3-Instance whenever a file is being played! This is probably what the creator of the MP3-Class had in mind when he wrote it :)

Comment: @GETah You suggest to create a new Thread from within an already existing Thread?? Not a very clean solution imho...

Comment: @quaylar No, notice that `MP3` class is no longer a thread but only a helper class. Creating nested threads is a very bad idea indeed :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to get familiar with Threads since this project you are working on uses them! Your class textbook may cover this topic.  Give it a careful read.  Threads are VERY important.  If your textbook is not clear, you can also [read the official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) .

Back to your question.  Every instance of your MP3 class runs in a separate Thread.  The MP3 thread is separate from the main program execution (meaning the thread that runs the main method) and the swing UI runs in a separate thread as well.

Your error is indicating that, to quote the Javadocs for `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` :

> a thread is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.
>   See, for example, the suspend and resume methods in class Thread.

Here are some things to look at:

1. Your timer class can stop and start the MP3 thread.  It calls playSong(current); and stopPlayback().  Is there another class also calling these methods?  Your error was triggered by a user event: pa2.MP3Random$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(MP3Random.java:373)
   Did you click the button before the Thread was ready to play?
2. In general, you need to make sure that two Threads do not interfere with each other.  A classic example would be two threads both modifying the same list.  If the first Thread deletes an item from the list while the second thread is iterating over the list (using an Iterator or for each loop) an exception will be thrown.
3. Can you test out the given classes for playing mp3s without a GUI?  Just a static method call.  Can you get the player to work?

Point number 2 is in my answer is probably not related to your problem - it is just important to understand when working with Threads. For instance if the list of available songs was to change in your PlaylistPanel (an multiple threads could change it) then you would need to make part of that class synchronized.  This forces a Thread to wait if another thread is running a synchronized method.  Your issue is trying to restart a thread that is "dead"  Look at the [JavaDocs for Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

So to start the thread, you call start.  Start calls run.  That thread will now "run" concurrently with other threads until run() terminates.  And once it terminates, we are done with that thread.  If we wanted the same thread to play multiple songs, we wound need to implement this behavior.  But the run method you posted (which I think you did not write; it was given as part of this assignment) is very simple.  It calls `player.play();` and when palay terminates, the thread is done.

I think  the last line of the run() method should be `player = null` so that the isPlaying() method will work properly.

Comment: Hi Thorn, thanks for the help!

the error does pop up immediately after pressing a button (not on the first button presses, but after a couple of next/back,stop-start clicks)

I understand your 2nd point, and that makes sense, although I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it from deep within the code.

Comment: @Wangagat Are you creating a new MP3-instance each time a song needs to be played?

Comment: This is a fun assignment. What class is it for?

Comment: @Thorn, `It's not immediately clear to me what the root cause of this error is` The stack trace is a good place to start with :) see my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but: Could it be, that you are calling methods on AWT-Widgets from your threads? For SWT this would not work for example, widget-calls must be called from the GUI-Thread, i.e. the thread that created them.
Not sure of this is the same for AWT, but its worth to check...

Comment: That is unlikely.  The most likely answer is what was already said.  A new mp3 object must be created each time a song needs to be played.  I was unable to get the given code to compile.  We  are missing the classes:
    MainPanel extends JPanel and 
    PlaylistPanel extends JPanel

Comment: @Thorn Correct, see my comment on GETah's answer.